# Trouble adding data to database using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add data to a table in my database using AJAX and I'm having trouble.  As my script works now, there's only one field being added, the others are not being added and I'm not sure why.  I know with what I'm posting has SQL injection vulnerabilities, but I'm just trying to make the functionality work for this demo project.

**HTML**

```
<div id="form_emergencies" class="form_view">
   <div class="half" id="systems"></div>
   <div class="half" id="malfunctions"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var Alerts = {
    apu: [["APU Power Fail", "APU[1]"], ["APU Power Fault", "APU[2]"], ["APU Generator Fail", "APU[3]"], ["APU High Oil Temperature", "APU[4]"], ["APU Hot Start", "APU[5]"], ["APU Loss Overspeed Protection", "APU[6]"], ["APU Starter Engaged", "APU[7]"], ["APU Fire", "APU[8]"], ["APU Fails Bite Check", "APU[9]"], ["APU Door Fails to Open", "APU[10]"], ["APU No Flame", "APU[11]"], ["Left Fire Bottle Discharge", "APU[12]"]],

    avionics: [["ADS 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[1]"], ["ADS 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[2]"], ["ADS 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[3]"], ["AP 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[4]"], ["AP 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[5]"], ["Autopilots Fail", "AVIONICS[6]"], ["Baroset 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[7]"], ["Baroset 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[8]"], ["Baroset 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[9]"], ["CCD 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[10]"], ["CCD  2 Fail", "AVIONICS[11]"], ["Heading Comparison Monitor", "AVIONICS[12]"], ["Heading and Roll Comparison Monitor", "AVIONICS[13]"], ["Display Controller 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[14]"], ["Display Controller 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[15]"], ["IRS 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[16]"], ["IRS 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[17]"], ["IRS 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[18]"], ["Glideslope Antenna Fail", "AVIONICS[19]"], ["MAU 1A Fail", "AVIONICS[20]"], ["MAU 1B Fail", "AVIONICS[21]"], ["MAU 2A Fail", "AVIONICS[22]"], ["MAU 2B Fail", "AVIONICS[23]"], ["MAU 3A Fail", "AVIONICS[24]"], ["MAU 3B Fail", "AVIONICS[25]"], ["MRC 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[26]"], ["MRC 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[27]"], ["GPS Degrade", "AVIONICS[28]"], ["GPS #1 Fail", "AVIONICS[28]"], ["GPS #2 Fail", "AVIONICS[30]"], ["Display Unit 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[31]"], ["Display Unit 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[32]"], ["Display Unit 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[33]"], ["Display Unit 4 Fail", "AVIONICS[34]"], ["GPS - Unable RNP", "AVIONICS[35]"]]
}
var description, breaker;
for(var key in Alerts){
    var system = key.toUpperCase();
    $("#systems").append("<div class='systems' id='" +key +"'><div class='select_box'></div><h2>" +system +"</h2></div>");
}
$("#systems").on("click", ".systems", function(){
    $("#malfunctions").children().remove();
    $(this).find(".select_box").each(function(){
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    })
    $.each(Alerts[this.id], function(ind,item){
        description = item[0];
        breaker = item[1];
        $("#malfunctions").append("<div class='systems' data-key='" +key +"' data-breaker='" +breaker +"' data-id='" +description +"'><div class='select_box'></div><p>" +description +"</p></div>");
    })
})
$("#malfunctions").on("click", ".systems", function(){
    var key = $(this).data("key");
    var breaker = $(this).data("breaker");
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $(this).find(".select_box").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            $.post("../php/processing.php", {system: key, description: description, breaker: breaker}, function(response){
                if(response.success == "1"){
                }
            })
            console.log(key);
            console.log(id);
            console.log(breaker);
        }
    })
})
```

**PHP header**

//In header file

```
 $create_table_malfunctions = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $malfunctions(scenario_id VARCHAR(100), system VARCHAR(10), description VARCHAR(50), breaker VARCHAR(10))";
```

//In processing file

```
ob_start();
    require("../includes/header.php");
    if($_POST["save"]){
        header("Location: ../pages/instructor.php");
        $instructor = $_POST["name"];
        $initials = $_POST["initials"];
        $date = $_POST["date"];
        $center = $_POST["center_menu"];
        $pair1 = $_POST["pair1"];
        $pair2 = $_POST["pair2"];
        $scenario = $pair1 .$pair2;
        $id = $scenario .substr(strtoupper($center, 0,4)) .$date .$initials;
        $system = $_REQUEST["system"];
        $description = $_REQUEST["description"];
        $breaker = $_REQUEST["breaker"];
        ob_clean();

        $insert_malfunctions = "INSERT INTO `$malfunctions`(`scenario_id`, `system`, `description`, `breaker`) VALUES('" .$id ."', '" .$system ."', '" .$description ."', '" .$breaker ."')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $insert_malfunctions);
        echo json_encode(array("success" => 1));
    }
```

I also have two additional queries in the processing script which adds data into other tables, but I don't think they would be creating the issue.  Also, would having the PHP check for the submit button's post value be creating an issue?  As it works now, the only field that's eing added to the database is the `scenario_id` field.

Here's the network response that I'm getting.
[image]

Comment: Not sure why my HTML is needed as that's got nothing to do with the question, but I'll add it.

Comment: Which is that field is correctly added into table?

Comment: inspect the actual request in browser console network tab to see what is actually being sent

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: Using Firebug in firefox

Comment: hit F12 then look for network tab

Comment: I don't have firebug and don't have permissions to download it.

@charlietfl ok

Comment: @charlietfl I'm getting a 302 yellow arrow.  I'm clueless as to what that means.  I'll add a screenshot to show the output.

Comment: @Robert http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E302.html

Comment: looking for more than status too, can dig in deeper and see headers, data sent, response body etc

Comment: @charlietfl I added a screenshot of the console log

Comment: image doesn't help much , look at `params`

Comment: ah, ok, so I see that the PHP isn't actually getting the variable from AJAX

Comment: @Robert, the 302 yellow arrow indicates that the initial request to processing.php is being **redirected** to instructor.php because you have header("Location: ../pages/instructor.php"); in there. It could be that this redirect is causing an additional GET request (instead of POST) so you immediately lose the $_POST variables from your original request. I suggest working with a smaller sample of code and then adding more. See my comments in your duplicate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717451/why-would-my-ajax-script-not-pass-variables-to-php-to-pass-into-my-database).

Answer (score 0):

Put the header at the end after the insert because the header is redirecting the page before the insert and hence losing the post data.

```
header("Location: ../pages/instructor.php");
```

Also change this;

```
$insert_malfunctions = "INSERT INTO " . $malfunctions . "( scenario_id, system, description, breaker) VALUES('" .$id ."', '" .$system ."', '" .$description ."', '" .$breaker ."')";
```