# Why would my AJAX script not pass variables to PHP to pass into my database?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX script that I need to pass variable data into a database, however, the script is not doing this.  I've notice on the console window in the params tab that the variables aren't actually being passed over the network.  Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var Alerts = {
    apu: [["APU Power Fail", "APU[1]"], 
          ["APU Power Fault", "APU[2]"], 
          ["APU Generator Fail", "APU[3]"], 
          ["APU High Oil Temperature", "APU[4]"], 
          ["APU Hot Start", "APU[5]"], 
          ["APU Loss Overspeed Protection", "APU[6]"], 
          ["APU Starter Engaged", "APU[7]"], 
          ["APU Fire", "APU[8]"], 
          ["APU Fails Bite Check", "APU[9]"], 
          ["APU Door Fails to Open", "APU[10]"], 
          ["APU No Flame", "APU[11]"], 
          ["Left Fire Bottle Discharge", "APU[12]"]],

    avionics: 
          [["ADS 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[1]"], 
          ["ADS 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[2]"], 
          ["ADS 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[3]"], 
          ["AP 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[4]"], 
          ["AP 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[5]"], 
          ["Autopilots Fail", "AVIONICS[6]"], 
          ["Baroset 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[7]"], 
          ["Baroset 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[8]"], 
          ["Baroset 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[9]"], 
          ["CCD 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[10]"], 
          ["CCD  2 Fail", "AVIONICS[11]"], 
          ["Heading Comparison Monitor", "AVIONICS[12]"], 
          ["Heading and Roll Comparison Monitor", "AVIONICS[13]"], 
          ["Display Controller 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[14]"], 
          ["Display Controller 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[15]"], 
          ["IRS 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[16]"], 
          ["IRS 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[17]"], 
          ["IRS 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[18]"], 
          ["Glideslope Antenna Fail", "AVIONICS[19]"], 
          ["MAU 1A Fail", "AVIONICS[20]"], 
          ["MAU 1B Fail", "AVIONICS[21]"], 
          ["MAU 2A Fail", "AVIONICS[22]"], 
          ["MAU 2B Fail", "AVIONICS[23]"], 
          ["MAU 3A Fail", "AVIONICS[24]"], 
          ["MAU 3B Fail", "AVIONICS[25]"], 
          ["MRC 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[26]"], 
          ["MRC 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[27]"], 
          ["GPS Degrade", "AVIONICS[28]"], 
          ["GPS #1 Fail", "AVIONICS[28]"], 
          ["GPS #2 Fail", "AVIONICS[30]"], 
          ["Display Unit 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[31]"], 
          ["Display Unit 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[32]"], 
          ["Display Unit 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[33]"], 
          ["Display Unit 4 Fail", "AVIONICS[34]"], 
          ["GPS - Unable RNP", "AVIONICS[35]"]]
}
var description, breaker;
for(var key in Alerts){
    var system = key.toUpperCase();
    $("#systems").append("<div class='systems' id='" +key +"'><div class='select_box'></div><h2>" +system +"</h2></div>");
}
$("#systems").on("click", ".systems", function(){
    $("#malfunctions").children().remove();
    $(this).find(".select_box").each(function(){
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    })
    $.each(Alerts[this.id], function(ind,item){
        description = item[0];
        breaker = item[1];
        $("#malfunctions").append("<div class='systems' data-key='" +key +"' data-breaker='" +breaker +"' data-id='" +description +"'><div class='select_box'></div><p>" +description +"</p></div>");
    })
})
$("#malfunctions").on("click", ".systems", function(){
    var key = $(this).data("key");
    var breaker = $(this).data("breaker");
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $(this).find(".select_box").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            $.post("../php/processing.php", {system: key, description: description, breaker: breaker}, function(response){
                if(response.success == "1"){
                }
            })
            console.log(key);
            console.log(id);
            console.log(breaker);
        }
    })
})
```

PHP header

//In header file

```
 $create_table_malfunctions = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $malfunctions(
          scenario_id VARCHAR(100), 
          system VARCHAR(10), 
          description VARCHAR(50), 
          breaker VARCHAR(10))";
```

//In processing file

```
ob_start();
    require("../includes/header.php");
    if($_POST["save"]){
        header("Location: ../pages/instructor.php");
        $instructor = $_POST["name"];
        $initials = $_POST["initials"];
        $date = $_POST["date"];
        $center = $_POST["center_menu"];
        $pair1 = $_POST["pair1"];
        $pair2 = $_POST["pair2"];
        $scenario = $pair1 .$pair2;
        $id = $scenario .substr(strtoupper($center, 0,4)) .$date .$initials;
        $system = $_REQUEST["system"];
        $description = $_REQUEST["description"];
        $breaker = $_REQUEST["breaker"];
        ob_clean();

        $insert_malfunctions = "INSERT INTO `$malfunctions`
                   (`scenario_id`, `system`, `description`, `breaker`) 
                   VALUES
                   ('" .$id ."', '" .$system ."', 
                    '" .$description ."', '" .$breaker ."')";

        mysqli_query($connect, $insert_malfunctions);
        echo json_encode(array("success" => 1));
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a var_dump just after "if($_POST["save"]){" to see if it is being passed at all?

Comment: You have a condition in the PHP script that checks for $_POST['save'], but I do not see you passing this post variable from your Javascript via $.post, therefore the majority of your PHP code never fires. This might work: $.post("../php/processing.php", {**save: true**, system: key, description: description, breaker: breaker}, function(response){ ... }

Comment: My suggestion: Don't use the shorthand `$.post(` syntax. Use the `$.ajax(` syntax and make sure to include `cache: false,` because this is probably a browser caching issue.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is your PHP script making use of many $_POST variables that are not being passed from Javascript e.g. $_POST["pair1"] is going to be empty because you are only passing "system", "description" and "breaker" variables from Javascript. You then use $_REQUEST in the PHP script to pull in other posted variables e.g. $_REQUEST["system"] when simply $_POST["system"] would work fine and be more consistent.

Comment: @developerwjk: HTTP POST requests are never cached.

Comment: @James Elliott: I think he'd want to do var_dump($_POST) *before* if($_POST['save']){ ... I also don't think the OP needs ob_start() or ob_clean() as there is no output buffering required (there is only one echo at the end). It's strange to see a Header() redirect right after if($_POST['save']){ without a die() as this would indicate all of the code after Header() is going to be executed despite the redirect. Maybe the need for output buffering is obscured in the Header() redirect, but I couldn't tell by the code provided...

Comment: @Evan Mulawski, I think its supposed to be that way but I don't think the IE development team got the memo.

Answer (score 0):

You have a condition in the PHP script that checks for $_POST['save'], but I do not see you passing this post variable from your Javascript via $.post, therefore the majority of your PHP code never fires.

This might get your PHP script working:

$.post("../php/processing.php", {**save: true**, system: key, description: description, breaker: breaker}, function(response){ ... }

However, you have a header() redirect that might produce undesired results. The 302 yellow arrow (I'm referring to your other duplicate thread) indicates that the initial request to processing.php is being redirected to instructor.php because you have header("Location: ../pages/instructor.php"); in there. It could be that this redirect is causing an additional GET request (instead of POST) so you immediately lose the $_POST variables from your original request.

Another thing I noticed is your PHP script making use of many $_POST variables that are not being passed from Javascript e.g. $_POST["pair1"] is going to be empty because you are only passing "system", "description" and "breaker" variables from Javascript. You then use $_REQUEST in the PHP script to pull in posted variables e.g. $_REQUEST["system"] when simply $_POST["system"] would work fine and be more consistent.

You have some unnecessary/cluttery code. I would suggest paring it down to get a minimum amount of code functioning via AJAX POST, then throw in the rest of the variables later.